# How to deliver SSR version of SPA (React) only to search robots

Tags: reactjs, seo, single-page-application, user-agent, server-side-rendering

We are finishing website on React but for SEO purposes we need to identify useragent and "deliver" for search engine crawlers a static version (SSR) of website, and normal SPA to other useragents. I found that with next.js we can make SSR but it seems website will be SSR for all useragents in this case.

So the issue is how to identify useragent and deliver version of website (SPA/CSR or SSR) depending on useragent type.

I know that there are a way if setup Nginx in front of React server to route (kinda proxy) requests. But I'm interested in React only solution

Comment: well this is what we did. first we created an check on server side which decides to show SSR or clientside component based on a query string value in the url. Then in the sitemap we add that querystring value to all urls and voila only SSR for SEO robots.

Comment: so you parsed url? but I have the same url for robots and other useragents, let's say mysite.com/index I need it's ssr version to be indexed  

Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: I assume the SEO robots are using your sitemap.xml file to move through your website. when a regular person visits he goes to mysite.com/index but the url you have put in the sitemap file is mysite.com/index?srr=true

Comment: on the serverside, I check for the existance of the querystring value ssr and act accordingly

Comment: I would suggest relay on the header, I noticed that if the user copy-paste my SPA URL in social network they won't work properly to show the preview card, right now thinking about generating  a simple version of the website with required meta  just for social robots, For SEO I am not sure what I am going to deal with.

Comment: deploy the normal SSR server and a static website too, then set a load balancer (AWS ALB) or reverse proxy (Nginx) in front, and there you can write some rules to decide where the client should go, based on the client User-Agent HTTP header. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-route-traffic-custom-http-header

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about **robots.txt** file.
You may add this file inside **static folder** and define in **server.js**

```
const options = {
              root: path.join(__dirname + '/../static/'),
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
              }
            };

            server.get('/robots.txt', (req, res) => (
              res.status(200).sendFile('robots.txt', options)
            ));
```

Comment: thanks, but not about robots.txt. But about whole website static version